# can't resolve hostnames from cloudera quickstart docker container

Tags: centos, docker

started the image with a 
`docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -d --name quickstart0 -v /scratch/quickstart.cloudera/data:/data --publish-all=true -p 8888:8888 -p 7180:7180 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart`

I can ping 8.8.8.8, no problem, but:

```
[root@quickstart /]# ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

resolv.conf

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
search XXXXX.comcast.net
```

- tried to replace for 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 with no luck
- pinging outside the container works

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.39 (downgraded from 1.40)
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:27:04 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:06:30 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-in-rhel-8) there's no other elegant solution now for this other than:

```
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```